# Groups of n and m people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many ways are there to pick a group of *n* people from 100 people ( each of a different height) and then pick a second group of *m* other people such that all people in the first group are taller than the people in the second group?

I have no idea how to begin this quesiton

Comment: Just pick $n+m$ people. Then assign the tallest $n$ people to the first group.